# Apache show file index as utf-8

Tags: apache, htaccess, content-encoding, unicode

I'm on a shared hosting which runs Apache on a Windows server. I am running Linux and I have uploaded some files that should be accessible directly via a public URL (that is known only by a few people). Now, some of these files contains accented characters (ex: "encyclopédie.pdf") but the file index show the files with replacement symbols (ex: "encyclopÃ©die.pdf"). Can I correct this via `.htaccess` specifying the charset of the index? Or do I have to rename the files without accents?

Answer (score 6):

Alright, after some digging, [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html) is what I have found (and it works).

```
IndexOptions Charset=UTF-8
```

Cheers!